# Angular 4, use html without Component backing

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm using Angular 4, and as of now my application follows the following pattern with

something.component.ts
  something.component.html
  something.component.css

However, I would like to have a raw html ("legal.html") file and reference it in the "something.component.html" view but I'm not sure about where to even start or what question to ask.

"legal.html" will also have to be bind to the parent controller too (something.component.ts).

Any help on getting something like this to work:

legal.html

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

something.component.html

```
<div>
   I'm something
   <legal>
</div>
```

is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so do you want to create some html piece and share it between the templates of several components? somehting line ng-include from AngularJS?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Yes.  Now html piece will have to bind to the parent component.  But that's about it.

Comment: what do you mean "bind"? also, do you want that to happen during runtime or can be merged into component template during build time?

Comment: What's the problem of just creating a component instead?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think it seems kind of excessive to create a component that won't do too much. But I assume since I'm going to be using binding that I might as well.

Comment: Create a component. Components are main building block in Angular, even if they are template-only. I sometimes even have a component whose template is just `<ng-content></ng-content>`, just so I can add some styles to it.

Comment: If you _REALLY_ want to do it the way you suggest, use some webpack loader that will transform your templates before Angular even comes to them.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Thanks, I'll create the component for now and from now on.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is component. 
You can simple create a new component using following command

```
ng g component legal
```

Then in legat.component.html file write your html then in your other html file you can simply refer to your code using selector tag

This link may be helpful 
[Angular component](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/56/Angular-4-Components-Tutorial)